# How to connect a different phone to the "Nexus One Desktop Dock"

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-nexus, nexus-one, docking-station, bluetooth-audio

The original HTC/Google Nexus One Desktop Dock is a bluetooth device and has audio line out. I would love to still be able to use this with my new phone. Anyone know how to connect this with a Galaxy Nexus?

Comment: Did you try to just turn bluetooth on on both your "new phone" (details could be helpful here) and the dock, and then discover the dock on your phone and pair it? Some basic functionality should be available at least, it may e.g. register with some audio profile.

Comment: @izzy the dock only accepts connection for the second a n1 phone is inserted. and then they exchange the password via the wired connection. It's not as trivial. and as vulnerable to Bluetooth scanners as any connection (pass still goes over the air). It's just annoying.

Answer (score 0):

against common sense, Google and htc decided that the dock and n1 phone would use a proprietary method to set up the Bluetooth connection. but if you can work around that annoyance, it's still a simple Bluetooth connection.

here are the steps http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=43401809&postcount=25

(I won't copy here because I'm on mobile. anyone feel free to edit it)

It involves using the Linux shell on your n1phone. sorry if you can't do that I doubt there's a solution. (I may write an app if a see myself doing that often tho :)

as a final lesson, don't buy stuff from those companies again if you want standards, convenience and interoperability.